# Automatically populate input field with data on clicking radio buttons

Tags: javascript

When the user selects a radio button in the 2 categories Plan details and Plan Duration the input field should populate with the relevant data through JavaScript.

Please check the html markup and JavaScript below and suggest corrections or an alternate method that would work.

```
<h3 class="fltClear">Plan Details</h3>
<div id="spryradio1">
<dt>Plan Type: <span class="required">*</span></dt>
<dd>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Silver" id="RadioGroup1_0" onClick="changeplanprice();" class="RadioGroup1" />
  Silver</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Gold" id="RadioGroup1_1" onClick="changeplanprice();" class="RadioGroup1" />
  Gold</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Platinum" id="RadioGroup1_2" onClick="changeplanprice();" class="RadioGroup1" />
  Platinum</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="All-in-one" id="RadioGroup1_3" onClick="changeplanprice();" class="RadioGroup1" />
  All-in-one</label>
<br>
<span class="radioRequiredMsg">Please make a selection.<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>
</dd>
</div>

<!--Plan Duration-->

<div id="spryradio2">
<dt>Plan Duration: <span class="required">*</span></dt>
<dd>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="Yearly" id="RadioGroup2_0" onClick="changeplanprice();" class="RadioGroup2" />
  Yearly</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="Quaterly" id="RadioGroup2_1" onClick="changeplanprice();" class="RadioGroup2" />
  Quaterly</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="Monthly" id="RadioGroup2_2" onClick="changeplanprice();" class="RadioGroup2" />
  Monthly</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="Other" id="RadioGroup2_3" onClick="changeplanprice();" class="RadioGroup2" />
  Other</label>
<br>
<span class="radioRequiredMsg">Please make a selection.<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>
</dd>
</div>

<!--Plan Price-->
<div>

     <script>
     function changeplanprice() {
         var plantype=document.getElementByClassName('RadioGroup1').value;
         var planduration=document.getElementByClassName('RadioGroup2').value;
         if(plantype=="Silver") {
             if(planduration=="Monthly")     {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 39.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Quaterly")  {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 79.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Yearly")    {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 124.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Other")     {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=false;
                 }
                 }
             else if(plantype=="Gold")  {
                 if(planduration=="Monthly")    {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 49.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Quaterly")  {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 99.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Yearly")    {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 179.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Other")     {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=false;
                 }
                 }
             else if(plantype=="Platinum")  {
                 if(planduration=="Monthly")    {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 59.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Quaterly")  {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 199.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Yearly")    {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='£ 279.98';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
                 }
             else if(planduration=="Other")     {
                 document.getElementById('Price').value='';
                 document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=false;
                 }
                 } }
        </script>
```

```
<div>
<dt><label for="Price">Plan Price:</label></dt>
<dd class="bg"><input type="text" name="Price" id="Price" size="80" class="input" readonly="readonly"  />
</dd>
</div>
```

Comment: It's better to give your code samples on http://jsfiddle.net so that we can play around with the working thing

Comment: @Travesty3: A JSFiddle is good, but the important parts of the code should be in the question, too!

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Ok, I won't decide which parts are important, so I just rolled it back to original and added the JSFiddle link.

Comment: @Travesty3 - we'd prefer to keep a copy of the code here as well as having a jsFiddle given that the survivability of a jsFiddle link is totally out of our control. Thanks.

Comment: My fault. Sorry for the troubles.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion that I will give is to have single

```
document.getElementById('Price').readOnly=true;
```

This will make your code more readable.
Second suggestion is that you can have 2 arrays one for plantype and other for planduration, and the radio-buttons instead of text, have array index as value.

This will not only make your code more readable, but also more manageable. 
Suppose if you have to add one planduration, you will have to add the same condition for all plantypes, where there is a possibility of missing out one case.

Answer (score 0):

Your function could use a little bit of cleanup, but there is one problem that I see. You are using `document.getElementByClassName(' ... ').value;`. This isn't correct. The function is actually `document.getElementsByClassName` (note Elements is plural). This function returns an array of all elements with that class name. So you cannot call `.value` directly on that. You would need to loop through the array of elements to find which element is checked and take the value of that.

Given that all the radio buttons of one group have the same name, and there is another function, `document.getElementsByName`, there is no reason to use `getElementsByClassName`.

I would change your function. This is tested and works, and is more easily scalable, in case you come up with new pricing options. All you would have to do is add on to the `prices` object:

```
function changeplanprice() {
    var plantype;
    var plantypes = document.getElementsByName('RadioGroup1');
    for (var i=0; i < plantypes.length; i++) {
        if (plantypes[i].checked)
            plantype = plantypes[i].value;
    }

    var planduration;
    var plandurations = document.getElementsByName('RadioGroup2');
    for (i = 0; i < plandurations.length; i++) {
        if (plandurations[i].checked)
            planduration = plandurations[i].value;
    }

    if (plantype === undefined || planduration === undefined)
        return;

    document.getElementById('Price').readOnly = (planduration != "Other");

    var prices = {
        "Silver":{
            "Monthly":"£ 39.98",
            "Quarterly":"£ 79.98",
            "Yearly":"£ 124.98",
            "Other":""
        },
        "Gold":{
            "Monthly":"£ 49.98",
            "Quarterly":"£ 99.98",
            "Yearly":"£ 179.98",
            "Other":""
        },
        "Platinum":{
            "Monthly":"£ 59.98",
            "Quarterly":"£ 199.98",
            "Yearly":"£ 279.98",
            "Other":""
        },
        "All-in-one":{
            "Monthly":"...",  /* prices weren't provided for All-in-one in the example */
            "Quarterly":"...",
            "Yearly":"...",
            "Other":""
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('Price').value = prices[plantype][planduration];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I deeply appreciate your help. Cheers.